# Pass an Object and a String via RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, microservices, resttemplate

My rest endpoint:

```
@PostMapping("/customerPolicyInfo")
public Map<String, Object> getCustomerPolicyInfo(@RequestParam String policyNumber, @RequestParam Claims authenticatedUserDetails) {
}
```

How to call this endpoint from another service using `RestTemplate`? It is a HTTP `POST` request?

My current code where I am calling this above endpoint looks like this:

```
Claims authenticatedUserDetails = (Claims) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

// create a map for post parameters
MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
map.add("policyNumber", policyNumber);
map.add("authenticatedUserDetails", authenticatedUserDetails.toString());

// build the request
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> entity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map, headers);

// send POST request
ResponseEntity<Map> response = null;
try {
    response = restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:8081/policy-service/customerPolicyInfo", entity, Map.class);
} catch (RestClientException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return response.getBody();
```

Comment: `@RequestParam` is used for query parameters, e.g. `http://example.com?param1=a&param2=b`. You could send the string as a `@RequestParam` but the client as a `@RequestBody`

Comment: Can you make the changes in the above code and post ? what exactly you want to show? If I send data via postman then the request going successfully with @RequestParam as well

Comment: Can you share any error, result when using resttemplate?